# Schema.org Organization: address vs. location

Tags: street-address, schema.org

In the [Organization schema](https://schema.org/Organization) there are properties for both [address](https://schema.org/address) and [location](https://schema.org/location).

What are some real world examples of when each should be used?

**Location**
The location of the event, organization or action.

**Address**
Physical address of the item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `location` is used on *events* and *actions*, but `address` is used on *persons* and *places*.

Either can be used for *organizations*.

If you have an organization and only have a postal address for it, use `address`.

If you have an organization and don't have the postal address for it, use `location`.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Looking into it some more, it seems that if a business was e.g. near a landmark, a `location` for the landmark could be used, and that `location` could have and `address`